# Find all traces satisfying a set of linear temporal logic (LTL) formulas

Tags: logic, automata, searching

I want to compute all finite traces up to a given length that satisfy a set of linear temporal logic formulas. Does such an algorithm exist?

Answer (score 0):

The set of finite words satifying a given LTL formula is a regular (and even [star-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-free_language)) language and there are known algorithms to convert a LTL formula into, say, a deterministic automaton accepting the corresponding language. Next the set of words up to a given length $n$ of a regular language $L$ of $A^*$: it is the intersection of $L$ with $(1 + A)^n$ and again there are known algorithms to compute the intrersection of two regular languages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you have examples of such algorithms?